# Backing up Outlook Archive on Domain

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange

I'm wondering if anyone has come across a good solution or method for backing up a Business's Outlook Archive files that the users create. Folder Redirection just seems to break things when it comes to .pst files, so that doesn't seem to be an option.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I normally just create copy of the file.  This is a tough question to answer without providing a software recommendation.

Comment: This is a conundrum we experience at least once a week where I work... the best solutions are, unfortunately, as Ramhound says, to use a third-party software (that we can't recommend here) or increase the user mailbox sizes and educate users to manage their mailboxes better... Could you look at the Windows offline folders settings so that the files are archived locally but when the user logs off they are synchronised back to the server?

Comment: What specific issue are you trying to address? How often are you archiving/ backing up etc.?

Comment: @BigChris, I don't recommend using offline folders with PST files, you will almost certainly end up with quite a lot of corrupted files.

Comment: The only realistic and reliable way of doing this is so painful to users that you might as well not bother. PST's are only reliable at small sizes and when not kept open for long periods and not on network drives. So users have to regularly create new PST's and close the old ones, only then can they reliably be copied/move to a backup location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the responses!

My clients are all SMB's, so I think the solution is to just allow for larger Exchange Mailboxes and educating users to NOT archive, Since dealing with Archive files seems to be nothing but a hassle. Someone mentioned increasing mailbox sizes in the comments.

A 3rd party application seems to be the only bet for Archives for Pop based email accounts. Unless someone has an alternative though?

Answer (score 0):

Outlook Archives are generally not used as intended in an office environment. Best Practices means not having the archive on a network drive, and until recently not exceeding 2GB (2007 - 2013 is 50GB).

Archives as a backup solution are OK, but if either of the two conditions above are not met archives are not stable, tend to corrupt or disconnect.

That said, I see two approaches depending on the environment (although neither is a solution in itself):

1) Treat archives as any other backup method. Keep a copy locally perhaps and backup regularly. Perhaps to the users Home drive nightly/ weekly.

2) Move away from Outlook archives and to something like [Exchange Archives](http://web.archive.org/web/20150331171156/http://www.microsoft.com/exchange/en-us/archiving-and-retention.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

We use Office 365 and have a retention policy set by the Exchange Admin to archive old e-mails (90 days) to the Online Archive. Every Outlook item is tagged with a retention policy. When it is time, the Outlook item will get moved to the Online Archive. On the client side, you might be able to hide or disable the Outlook client from archiving (creating PST) via Group Policy.